# jomsocial ask for login everytime the user post anything to the wall

Tags: post, authentication, posting, jomsocial

After logging in when trying to post either text or photo or anything in the wall, it proceed the post successfully but it popup the log in window for entering the username and password again, if the user put the username and password then it asks again and again if he posts again.
however if the user didn't fill the username it considered his as guest, and when trying to enter jomsocial again it gives the following error:

1064 Error
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY `groupid`' at line 1 SQL=SELECT `groupid` FROM `xx756_community_groups_members` WHERE `approved` = 1 AND `memberid` = GROUP BY `groupid`

and if login again via forum kunena the error disappear and again it asks for login when posting anything.

Kindly Please someone help me

Comment: Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

1. Open PHPmyAdmin
2. Backup xxxx_community_groups table
3. Execute this query

   SELECT `member`.groupid, `group`.id 
   FROM `wottide_community_groups_members` AS `member` LEFT JOIN `xxxx_community_groups` AS `group` ON (`member`.groupid = `group`.id ) WHERE `group`.id IS NULL
4. If the result not empty. Delete it.